# querydsl libray conflic org.freemarker

Tags: java, email, freemarker, querydsl

When I import freemarker gradle in my project that use querydsl before. But when I build project, querydsl can't generate Qclass properly.

```
implementation group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.28'
```

```
// QueryDSL 4.4.0
implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${queryDslVersion}")
implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}")
annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa")
testImplementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}")
testAnnotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa")
annotationProcessor("jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api")
annotationProcessor("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're issue is unrelated to the introduction of Freemarker.

With the `jakarta.persistence-api` you need to use Querydsl version 5.0.0 minimally and also specify the `jakarta` classifier instead of `jpa` for `querydsl-apt` and `querydsl-jpa`.